# PyTorch has CUDA version 11.7 whereas TorchAudio has CUDA version 11.8

Tags: python

> RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and TorchAudio were compiled with
> different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA version 11.7 whereas
> TorchAudio has CUDA version 11.8. Please install the TorchAudio
> version that matches your PyTorch version.

I tried to install TorchAudio version that matches your PyTorch version but I don't know which version it should be ?

Comment: Tell us more infomation, for example, how do you install PyTorch and TorchAudio? Did you follow the official steps: [Building on Linux and macOS — Torchaudio 2.0.1 documentation](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/build.linux.html)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.